# A/C causes the the car to die

Tags: engine, ford, ac, escort

I have a 1999 ford ecsort Zx2 it has the 2.0L DOHC engine in it or known as the Ztec engine. When I am driving with the A/C on it sputers and dies but restarts. What would cause this? it runs just fine and doesnt die if it is off. Driving down the road it runs with no isses with the A/C on. It only try to die at low rpm at idle.

Comment: Does it die when idling and not when you are cruising down the road? Does it just do this when stopped and you turn the A/C on? Is this a new thing or has it been happening for a while and is getting worse?

Answer (score 2):

Your AirCon compressor comes in two halves. There is the pulley/clutch half, and the pumping element half. With the AirCon off the pulley and clutch arrangement are simply rotated by the serpentine belt, and the pumping element remains stationary. When you turn the AirCon on, the clutch is engaged and both elements turn together to pressurise the system. The system is further turned on and off by a pressure sensor on max pressure, and the throttle pedal position on full acceleration. Your problem lies with a partially seizing compressor, or a shorting electrical clutch. Both instances would cause an excessive engine load causing the symptoms you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is something wrong with your a/c pump or in the circle, so it's stiff. But at that way you should hear a pretty hard beat or squeak if A/C turns on, because the magnetic clutch of A/C is overloaded. The second reason could the short circuit, so I would check some cable. I think this is more an electrically problem.